# How to change the browser used for web results in Windows 10 Search

Tags: windows-10, firefox, windows-search

When I search for things in Windows 10, the (web) results open up in Microsoft Edge with the Bing search engine.

I want the results to open in my default browser, Firefox, in my default search engine, DuckDuckGo.

What I have tried:

- extensions: either not compatible with Firefox or just didn't work
- changing Firefox config value `browser.search.redirectWindowsSearch` to `true`
- "uninstalling" Edge: because Microsoft don't give you a nice of way of doing this (at least with the latest feature update (version 1803)), I deleted the folder from the app directory. Now web search results are basically broken: it still tries to open Edge and it obviously fails.

Surely there is Registry edit that can save me from this.

Comment: Might want to look into EdgeDeflector. An open-source app made specifically to change the default Cortana search web browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the [EdgeDeflector project](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector/commit/23ab3f6c12f3dd56be629a93d247fbe5a4fe62a6) is discontinued [thanks to MS!](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/microsoft-edge-protocol-competition.html)

There seems to be [a new way](https://github.com/rcmaehl/MSEdgeRedirect)

or you could simply not use the Win search box altogether if that's what MS wants ;)

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this since it's more up to date.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @Fanatique for suggesting [EdgeDeflector](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector). After installing it, web results open in my default browser (Firefox).

*Note: I also had to install the [Bing to DuckDuckGo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bingtoduckduckgo/?src=search) add-on which changes the search engine to DuckDuckGo. Using Bing to DuckDuckGo will also redirect manual attempts to reach bing.com*

**Update:**

If the initial dialog to choose EdgeDeflector was dismissed (or did not pop-up), you can apply the change in Windows settings:

"Default apps" **>** "Choose default apps by protocol" (link at the bottom) **>** "MICROSOFT-EDGE" **>** Choose "EdgeDeflector".

[image]

Comment: Seems that this solution has been recently (as of Dec 2021) blocked by Microsoft - https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/microsoft-edge-protocol-competition.html. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

There is also now a "new" version of **Bing to Duckduckgo** called [Bing to whatever](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bing-to-whatever/) (Firefox) by the same author.
In it's settings you can choose between different search engines (including Google, Duckduckgo, Qwant and more).